# How do I reset all GSettings key to their default values?

Tags: command-line, gsettings

I want to *reset* **all** keys in the **GSettings** to their *default* values; preferably using a single command, or a simple bash script. How can I get that done?

Answer (score 8):

Generally you can reset one key to its default value with

```
gsettings reset SCHEMA [:PATH]  KEY
```

So you might use a bash script to do for all available keys.
Something like (pseudocode):

```
for i in /dir/of/keys
do
    gsettings reset <key-path>
done
```

Look at its man-page for more information: [man gsettings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gsettings.1.html)

Comment: a little more help with the _dir-of-keys_ please... and can I use wild cards there for key path?...

Comment: I mean where you have the keys. If you know the key then you can do it.

Answer (score 6):

The following will reset all those settings which are "non-relocatable". That is, the ones that are stored at a standard location and hence do not need an extra path specified after them. For example it will reset all keys of `org.gnome.eog.fullscreen`, but none of `org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/`.
It only does so for the user executing it.

`gsettings list-schemas | xargs -n 1 gsettings reset-recursively`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some media keys,they just worked sometimes so i needed to reboot or reset them manually with dconf-editor or gsettings.

maybe you could do a bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#To get in a list all the keys of that directory
list=$(gsettings list-keys <keys-path-directory>); 
for i in $list; do
    echo "resetting $i";
    gsettings reset <keys-path-directory> $i;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux systems, GSettings uses dconf for its backend. For any settings that do not appear in the user’s db, dconf returns an empty value (or searches down the hierarchy [if a profile is defined](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man7/dconf.7.html)), and GSettings falls back to the default value. Therefore, in order to reset ***all*** GSettings keys to their default or system fallback values on Linux, simply [wipe out the dconf database](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/dconf.1.html) for the user:

```bash
dconf reset -f /
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a helpful script:

```
#!/bin/bash
schema="org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings"  # Change this to your target schema
keys=$(gsettings list-keys $schema)        # Get the list of keys for the specified schema
for key in $keys; do                       # Iterate through the keys and reset each one
    gsettings reset $schema $key
done
```