# How do I reset a Gnome Extension's settings to default? Ex: for "Awesome Tiles" in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, settings, gnome-shell-extension

I installed the [Awesome Tiles](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4702/awesome-tiles/) Gnome Extension in Ubuntu 22.04 via the `gnome-shell-extension-manager` [since installing via the browser doesn't work due to a bug in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1418937/327339), and changed some keyboard shortcuts in the settings. I want to reset them all to default. If I uninstall and reinstall the extension, that does *not* reset its settings. How do I reset its settings?

Update: Related:

1. [Google search for "where are gnome extensions settings stored?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=where+are+gnome+extensions+settings+stored%3F&oq=where+are+gnome+extensions+settings+stored%3F&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.213j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
2. [Where are gnome extensions preferences stored?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1178587/327339)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick summary

Open dconf Editor (install with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`) and navigate to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions` --> right-click on the extension you'd like to reset --> click "Reset recursively" --> click "Apply" in the bottom-right. Done.

### Details

Thank goodness for knowledgeable people who write things down. This answer gave me the clues I needed to solve this: [Where are gnome extensions preferences stored?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1178587/327339)

I installed and ran `dconf-cli` to watch for where gsettings settings changes take place when I change the "Awesome Tiles" settings in its GUI, like this:

```bash
sudo apt install dconf-cli
# watch for GUI gsettings settings changes
dconf watch /
```

When I changed a keyboard shortcut in the "Awesome Tiles" settings via the `gnome-shell-extensions-manager` (open its GUI by pressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and typing "Extension Manager"; its icon is a blue puzzle piece), I was able to see on the command-line where I typed `dconf watch /` the following line:

```
/org/gnome/shell/extensions/awesome-tiles/shortcut-align-window-to-center
  ['grave']
```

That gives me the dconf location of the settings!: `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/awesome-tiles`.

So, from there I opened the dconf editor GUI and clicked around inside the editor until I figured it out. Here's the full solution:

### How to reset a Gnome Shell Extension's settings

Install and open the "dconf Editor":

```bash
# install it
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Open its GUI by pressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and typing "dconf Editor". Its icon is red.

Navigate to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions`, right-click on the extension whose settings you'd like to reset ("awesome-tiles" in my case), and go to "Reset recursively", as shown below.

This resets **all** of this extension's settings!:

[image]

Next, to apply the change, you have to click the "Apply" button:

[image]

If you'd just like to reset **some** of the settings to default, do this instead:

Navigate all the way into the extension: `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/awesome-tiles`, right-click the setting (key) you'd like to reset, and click "Erase key":

[image]

Do this for any settings (keys) you'd like to reset to defaults. When done, click the green "Apply" button in the bottom-right corner, same as above.

To **do the same thing as above from the command-line**, I tried this, *but was unable to get it to work* due to some "No such schema" errors which I was unable to resolve. I'll leave this here though in case anyone else wants to try to figure it out:

```bash
# [doesn't work actually :(] reset all settings for this extension
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.shell.extensions.awesome-tile

# [doesn't work actually :(] reset just this one setting (key)
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.awesome-tiles shortcut-align-window-to-center
```

### References:

1. [Where are gnome extensions preferences stored?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1178587/327339)
2. My own answer where I first used `gsettings`: [How to enable/disable the touchpad/trackpad in Ubuntu 22.04 from the command-line](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446479/327339)

### Related:

1. [How do I reset all GSettings key to their default values?](https://askubuntu.com/q/393772/327339)